# Springdoc and springboot 3 webflux issue

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc

I'm using springboot3 and spring webflux
In my maven I added the following

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
 <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to see my swagger.html page I type http://localhost:9079/swagger-ui.html but a white page is displayed

How can I make working springdoc with webflux? Is there any piece I'm missing?

Thank you
Angelo

Comment: Please check if you have any context-path defined? If yes the url would be http://localhost:9079/<your-context-path>/swagger-ui.html

Comment: Hi Mar-Z. I don't have context-path defined

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @JinKwon Yes it was my mistake in pom.xml